# Cordova for Android - javascript and jquery not working

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap

Javascript/Ajax/Jquery - none of those does seem to work in my Cordova-app (PhoneGap) for Android. All it shows is the htmlheader with its labels but the table is not populated with jsondata från an external url. I've tested it in a browser and it works perfect. But not for Android by the moment.

What could the problem be?

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *;">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"/>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="getLivsmedelsData.js"></script>

    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">

    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">

      <div class="livsmedelsmall">
          <h1>Sökning av livsmedel</h1>

          <form class="form">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="livsmedelsSokOrd">Livsmedel</label>
                  <input type="search" class="form-control" id="livsmedelsSokOrd" placeholder="t ex makaroner">
              </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="sok-button">Sök</button>
          </form>
          <table id="tabell" class="table">
              <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>Livsmedel</th>
                  <th>Energi (kcal/100g)</th>
                  <th>Kolhydrater</th>
                  <th>Protein</th>
                  <th>Fett</th>
              </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>

              </tbody>
          </table>
      </div>
  </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>


</body>
```

**getLivsmedelsData.js**

```
var dataList = {

isInLocalStorage: false,

init: function() {

    this.bindEvents();


},

bindEvents: function() {

    this.updateLocalStorage();

    var me = this;
    var parseCheck = setInterval(function() {
        if(this.isInLocalStorage){
            me.parseJSONdata();
            clearInterval(parseCheck);
        }
    }, 500);




},

parseJSONdata: function() {

    var rawJSONdata = window.localStorage.getItem("key");

    console.log('retrievedObject: ', JSON.parse(rawJSONdata));

    var jSONdata =  JSON.parse(rawJSONdata);

    jSONdata.forEach(function (item) {
    var newCells = new Array(5);
    var table = $('#tabell');
    var newRow = table.get(0).insertRow(-1);
    for (var k = 0; k < newCells.length; k++) {

        newCells[k] = newRow.insertCell(k);
    }
    newCells[0].innerHTML = item.namn;
    newCells[1].innerHTML = item.energi;
    newCells[2].innerHTML = item.kolhydrater;
    newCells[3].innerHTML = item.protein;
    newCells[4].innerHTML = item.fett;
    });


},

updateLocalStorage: function() {

    var targetVal = "pizza";

    var url1 = "https://webservice.informatik.umu.se/webservice_livsmedel/getlivsmedel.php";
    var url2 = url1.concat("?namn=");
    var url3 = url2.concat(targetVal);
    var theUrl = url3.concat("&callback=getLivsmedel");

    getJSONdata(this.result, targetVal, theUrl);


},

result: function(jsonData) {

    window.localStorage.setItem("key", JSON.stringify(jsonData));

    this.isInLocalStorage = true;

}


}



window.onload = function() {

dataList.init();

}


function getJSONdata(callback, target, theUrl) {

//Om det finns ett innehåll (dvs längden är större än 0)
if (target.length > 0) {

    //Utför en förfrågan till webbtjänsten
    $.ajax({
        url: theUrl,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data: {
            limit: 15,
            name: target
        },
        // Om förfrågan gått bra...
        success: function (response) {

            var foodArray = response.livsmedel;
                            callback(foodArray);

        }, error: function(xhr, status, error) {

                        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                        console.log(err);

                    }
    });
}
}
```

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.jsonajax.food" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org /ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
<feature name="Whitelist">
    <param name="android-package"  value="org.apache.cordova.whitelist.WhitelistPlugin" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>
<name>FoodData</name>
<description>
    A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready  event.
</description>
<author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
    Apache Cordova Team
</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<allow-intent href="market:*" />
<preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
```

Answer (score 0):

window.onload?  this is for browser only!

Where is your ondeviceready() function for cordova app?  should put the init() inside the ondeviceready() function

Comment: You should also create a Global variable, e.g. IsMobile, then at the very beginning of your js, check the url, if it contains 'http', set IsMobile to false.

If IsMobile is true, run init inside ondeviceready() ONLY, if and only if IsMobile is false, run init inside window.onload

Then you can write once run anywhere, including android/iphone app, and pc/mobile browsers.